# On Some Device Activity getting Destroyed after calling startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I want to perform a task when an app gets back from  `Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS` but after calling `startActivityForResult`  on the button click from activity A,  Activity A keeps getting destroyed after `startActivityForResult` is called and `onCreate` called again after coming back from wifi setting

here is the sample code that I have implemented

this is the caller method for starting activity

```
dialogButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            senddataflag = true;
            dialog.dismiss();

            startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 300);
        }
    });
```

Android Menifest File

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.UserDataDeviceActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
/>
```

Here is the Logcat result

```
2021-03-04 17:03:55.832 E: onCreate:
2021-03-04 17:03:55.882 E: onCreate: 
2021-03-04 17:03:56.119 E: onStart: 
2021-03-04 17:03:56.122 E: onResume: 
2021-03-04 17:03:56.141 E: onPause: 
2021-03-04 17:03:56.545 E: onResume: 
2021-03-04 17:04:01.084 E: onPause: 
2021-03-04 17:04:03.821 E: onStop: 
2021-03-04 17:04:03.877 E: onDestroy: 
2021-03-04 17:04:03.877 E: onDestroy: 
2021-03-04 17:04:08.822 E: onCreate: Bundle[{com.google.app_measurement.screen_service=Bundle[{referrer_name=UserDataDeviceActivity, id=3986266172732405302, name=null}], android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=1296], android:lastAutofillId=1073741823, android:fragments=android.app.FragmentManagerState@90bdd70}]
2021-03-04 17:04:08.853 E: onStart: 
2021-03-04 17:04:08.856 E: onActivityResult:  Result = 0
2021-03-04 17:04:08.857 E: onResume: 
2021-03-04 17:04:08.876 E: onPause: 
2021-03-04 17:04:09.274 E: onResume: 
2021-03-04 17:14:09.163 E: onPause: 
2021-03-04 17:14:09.249 E: onStop:
```

note that in other device is working fine but only on specific device activity is getting destroyed

Comment: don't think there's much you can do about it

Comment: Any time your app moves to the background, your process might be terminated while it is in the background. Whether or not this happens depends on a lot of factors, but it is always a possibility. Do not assume that this behavior is unique to some specific device.

This behavior is perfectly normal and it has been this way since Android 1.0.